# iOS URL Requests. Semaphore issues

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, semaphore

I'm entering the concurrency programming with some semaphore issues. 
My function first loads data from server, analyze received info and then, if necessary, makes second request to server.

I tried different ways to make it run, none of them did it well. 
My current code FOR ME seems to be correct, but on second request it just locks(maybe like a DeadLock) and the last log is "<__NSCFLocalDataTask: 0x7ff470c58c90>{ taskIdentifier: 2 } { suspended }"

Please, tell me what do I don't know. Maybe there is more elegant way to work with completions for these purposes?

Thank you in advance!

```
var users = [Int]()
let linkURL = URL.init(string: "https://bla bla")
let session = URLSession.shared()
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 0)
let dataRequest = session.dataTask(with:linkURL!) { (data, response, error) in
    let json = JSON (data: data!)
    if (json["queue"]["numbers"].intValue>999) {
        for i in 0...999 {
            users.append(json["queue"]["values"][i].intValue)
        }
        for i in 1...lround(json["queue"]["numbers"].doubleValue/1000) {
            let session2 = URLSession.shared()
            let semaphore2 = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 0)
            let linkURL = URL.init(string: "https://bla bla")
            let dataRequest2 = session2.dataTask(with:linkURL!) { (data, response, error) in
                let json = JSON (data: data!)
                print(i)
                semaphore2.signal()
            }
            dataRequest2.resume()
            semaphore2.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
        }
    }
    semaphore.signal()
}
dataRequest.resume()
semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
```

P.S. Why do I do it. Server returns limited count of data. To get more, I have to use offset.

Comment: Why you need the semaphore ?
Basically you need to run 2nd server request inside the closure of the first call and the second closure (inner one) should send the result via another closure. If you think it's what you need I'll give you a code snip.

Comment: @OhadM As I understand it correctly, closure runs on a different thread, so main thread doesn't wait for code in closure to be completed. In my case it doesn't even start to execute. Playground just stops. That's why I'm using semaphores.

Comment: 1. Closures will run on a different thread if you tell them to run on a different thread thus, they can also run on the main thread.
2. Why do you use playground ? you need to test your code in the whole app environment

Comment: @OhadM in Playground I test my app modules, it's faster than compile the whole app. Okay, so closure runs in background by default and to run it on the main thread, I have just to tell it using dispatch..get_global_queue, and make it twice: for the first request and for the second?

Comment: Closures run on the thread that you create them on, unless the function explicitly calls the callback on a different thread. In this case, all of them will be ran on the main thread unless you tell them otherwise.

Comment: @Rob these two requests are related. In the code above there is no second part, which appends data from second request to array which already contains data from the first. You know, in my vision it has to be too easy to make it on the main thread(like it was before with "sendSynchronousRequest"), but now I have to deal with closures and their native asynchrony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is deadlocking because you are waiting for a semaphore on the `URLSession`'s `delegateQueue`. The default delegate queue is not the main queue, but it is a serial background queue (i.e. an `OperationQueue` with a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `1`). So your code is waiting for a semaphore on the same serial queue that is supposed to be signaling the semaphore.

The tactical fix is to make sure you're not calling `wait` on the same serial queue that the session's completion handlers are running on. There are two obvious fixes:

1. Do not use `shared` session (whose `delegateQueue` is a serial queue), but rather instantiate your own `URLSession` and specify its `delegateQueue` to be a concurrent `OperationQueue` that you create:

   ```
   let queue = OperationQueue()
   queue.name = "com.domain.app.networkqueue"

   let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default()
   let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: queue)
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can solve this by dispatching the code with the semaphore off to some other queue, e.g.

   ```
   let mainRequest = session.dataTask(with: mainUrl) { data, response, error in
       // ...
       DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosUserInitiated).async {
           let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

           for i in 1 ... n {
               let childUrl = URL(string: "https://blabla/\(i)")!
               let childRequest = session.dataTask(with: childUrl) { data, response, error in
                   // ...
                   semaphore.signal()
               }
               childRequest.resume()
               _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
           }
       }
   }
   mainRequest.resume()
   ```

---

For the sake of completeness, I'll note that you probably shouldn't be using semaphores to issue these requests at all, because you'll end up paying a material performance penalty for issuing a series of consecutive requests (plus you're blocking a thread, which is generally discouraged).

The refactoring of this code to do that is a little more considerable. It basically entails issuing a series of concurrent requests, perhaps use "download" tasks rather than "data" tasks to minimize memory impact, and then when all of the requests are done, piece it all together as needed at the end (triggered by either a `Operation` "completion" operation or dispatch group notification).